# Angular Material Dialog return value

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material2

I have a following dialog component (which I open using `dialog.open(MyDialogComponent)` in another component):

```
export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I know I can return any data to the calling component by executing `matDialogRef.close(dataToReturn)` bound to a button in dialog component. But how can I return the data if a user clicked elsewhere but the popup to close it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If anybody is interested I found a solution (not sure if it is the best one). Just disabling the default close operation so the popup does not close on backround click, while closing it with data param on background click.

```
matDialogRef.disableClose = true;//disable default close operation
matDialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(result => {
  matDialogRef.close(dataToReturn);
});
```

This way the calling component receives the data whether the dialog was closed by button or clicked elsewhere.

Comment: You should also subscribe to keyboard events to handle the `esc` key. I browsed through the source code and don't really see a better way to do this. Luckily, the backdrop click and `esc` keydown event are the only two things that need to be reimplemented to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Where do you set the `dataToReturn` object ?

Comment: Just above the matDialogRef.close(dataToReturn); line. Remember that the subscribing takes place at the time of creating the dialog (and usually you are returning a value which is not known at that time), so setting the return value should be inside following lambda function result => { 
  let dataToReturn = ...;
  matDialogRef.close(dataToReturn);
})

Comment: Unfortunately the return type must be manually specified when calling `MatDialog.open<T, D, R>()`. Upvote this [feature request](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24538) to infer return-type `R` based on component passed into `MatDialog.open<T, D, R>()`

Answer (score 21):

Call the `close(dataToReturn)` in the `beforeClosed()` to set the dialog result:

```
constructor(public matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>) {
    matDialogRef.beforeClosed().subscribe(() => matDialogRef.close(this.dataToReturn));
}
```

This will work if the dialog is closed by clicking on the backdrop, or pressing the <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Comment: This is the right solution in Angular Material 7+ (maybe lower versions too, not sure). Also you can get if the user clicked yes, no or just escaped (mat-dialog-close) by the first argument passed into the subscribe method: `matDialogRef.beforeClose().subscribe((value) => matDialogRef.close(this.dataToReturn));
}`

Comment: this should be accepted answer. btw: typo, it should be beforeClose**d**

Comment: This is the right solution (Y)

Comment: just FYI, beforeClosed does complete, so there is no need to unsubscribe

Comment: From Angular Material v15, this results in a 'maximum call stack size exceeded' error

Answer (score 6):

```
    //In dialog component.
    dataYouWantToReturn = true; //set data.
            
    this.dialogRef.close(dataYouWantToReturn); 
               
    //In component calling the dialog component.
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
            console.log("Result is TRUE!");
        }
    });
```

You can also pass json objects such as below:

```
    //In dialog component.
    dataYouWantToReturn = {success: true, message: 'Result is TRUE!'}; //set data.
            
    this.dialogRef.close(dataYouWantToReturn); 
               
    //In component calling the dialog component.
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result.success) {
            console.log(result.message); //"Result is TRUE!"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will return default value if no other value has been provided.  Works with both backdrop and Esc clicks:

```ts
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {
    // return 'Cancel' when backdrop or 'Esc' clicked
    dialogRef.beforeClosed().subscribe(
       result => dialogRef.close(result ?? DialogResult.Cancel));
 }
    
  onYesClicked() {
    this.closeDialog(DialogResult.Yes);
  }

  onNoClicked() {
    this.closeDialog(DialogResult.No);
  }

  private closeDialog(result: DialogResult) {
    this.dialogRef.close(result);
  }

 export enum DialogResult {
   Cancel = -1,
   No = 0,
   Yes = 1,
 }
```

Comment: From Angular Material v15, this results in a 'maximum call stack size exceeded' error